# How to show menu according to session in php?

Tags: php, mysql, session

> I have 2 tables admin and superadmin. I have same login page for both
>   users. i can login according to query.i had create sessions for both
>   users. each table have column name roleID.  for superadmin roleID is
>   1, and for admin roleID is 2. Below is my code for login where i
>   create session. i used `print_r` and my session are working. Below is
>   my code for login page.

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['submit'])) 
{
        $username = $_REQUEST['user'];
        $password = $_REQUEST['pass'];
        $sql = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `accountants` where `acc_email` = '".$username."' AND `acc_pass` = '".$password."'");
        $data = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);        
        $_SESSION['role0']=$data['roleId'];
        $_SESSION['username']=$data['acc_name'];
        $sql1 = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `superadmin` where `username` = '".$username."' AND `password` = '".$password."'");
        $data1 = mysqli_fetch_array($sql1);        
        $_SESSION['role1']=$data1['roleId'];
        if ($data>0) 
            {
                header('Location: societyList.php');
            }
       elseif ($data1>0) {
                header('Location: home.php');
       }

       else
            {
                header('Location: index.php');
                echo 'incorrect login';
            }
}
```

> Now on home.php i have some menus to show accoording to roleID  my
>   code for menu.

```
<div id="sidebar-menu" class="main_menu_side hidden-print main_menu">
  <div class="menu_section">
    <h3>General</h3>
    <ul class="nav side-menu">        
      <li><a><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
        <ul class="nav child_menu">                      
          <li><a href="index01.php">Create Society</a></li>                     
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Master <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
        <ul class="nav child_menu">                      
          <li><a href="index1.php">Units</a></li>
          <li><a href="index2.php">Members</a></li>
          <li><a href="index2.php">Parking Lots</a></li>
          <li><a href="index2.php">Charges</a></li>
          <li><a href="index2.php">Chart of Account</a></li>
          <li><a href="index2.php">Interest Penalties</a></li>
          <li><a href="form_buttons.php">Billing Templates</a></li>
          <li><a href="form_buttons.php">Tax Structure</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Transactions <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
        <ul class="nav child_menu">
          <li><a href="form.php">Bill</a></li>
          <li><a href="form_advanced.php">Collection</a></li>
          <li><a href="form_validation.php">Expenses</a></li>
          <li><a href="form_wizards.php">Journal</a></li>
          <li><a href="form_upload.php">Bank Reco</a></li>
          <li><a href="form_buttons.php">Drop Box</a></li>
          <li><a href="form_upload.php">Online Payment</a></li>          
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a><i class="fa fa-desktop"></i> Reports <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
        <ul class="nav child_menu">
          <li><a href="general_elements.php">Income & Expenses</a></li>
          <li><a href="media_gallery.php">Balance Sheet</a></li>
          <li><a href="typography.php">Cash Flow</a></li>
          <li><a href="icons.php">Interest Calculation</a></li>                      
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="tables.php"><i class="fa fa-table"></i> Notices <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>  
      </li>
      <li><a><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o"></i> Registers <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
        <ul class="nav child_menu">
          <li><a href="chartjs.php">Form-I</a></li>                      
        </ul>
      </li>      
      <li><a><i class="fa fa-clone"></i> Forum <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
        <ul class="nav child_menu">
          <li><a href="fixed_sidebar.php">Cultural Activity</a></li>                      
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Domestic Help <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
        <ul class="nav child_menu">
          <li><a href="form.php">Request for Plumber</a></li>
          <li><a href="form_advanced.php">Request for Maid</a></li>
          <li><a href="form_validation.php">Request for House Cleaner</a></li>                      
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Emergency <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
        <ul class="nav child_menu">
          <li><a href="form.php">Ambulance</a></li>
          <li><a href="form_advanced.php">Fire Brigade</a></li>
          <li><a href="form_validation.php">Police</a></li>                      
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Helpdesk <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
        <ul class="nav child_menu">
          <li><a href="form.php">Request NOC for Tenancy</a></li>
          <li><a href="form_advanced.php">Request NOC for Home Loan</a></li>
          <li><a href="form_validation.php">Request NOC for Mortgage as collateral</a></li>
          <li><a href="form_wizards.php">Request for Vehicle Parking</a></li>
          <li><a href="form_upload.php">Application for Transfer</a></li>
          <li><a href="form_buttons.php">Request for waiver of interest</a></li>
          <li><a href="form_buttons.php">Request for waiver of a charge</a></li>
          <li><a href="form_buttons.php">Suggestion</a></li>
          <li><a><i class="fa fa-edit"></i><span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span>Complaint</a>
            <ul class="nav child_menu">
              <li><a href="form_buttons.php">About leakage</a></li>
              <li><a href="form_buttons.php">About tenants issues</a></li>
              <li><a href="form_buttons.php">About parking nuisance</a>
            </ul> 
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> CFO Desk Assists <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
        <ul class="nav child_menu">
          <li><a href="form.php">Tenant Rating</a></li>
          <li><a href="form_advanced.php">Owners Rating</a></li>
          <li><a href="form_validation.php">Your Reviews</a></li>                      
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Masters <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
        <ul class="nav child_menu">
          <li><a href="form.php">Auto Bank reconcilliation</a></li>
          <li><a href="form_advanced.php">AMC Masters</a></li>
          <li><a href="form_validation.php">Auto Adjust pending reference</a></li>
          <li><a href="form_wizards.php">Default GL for defined transactions</a></li>                      
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see lists. i want if `$_SESSION['role0']=$data['roleId'];` in session so first 4 lists will be visible for him only.
If `$_SESSION['role1']=$data['roleId'];` in session then rest of all lists will be display to him.
How to done it please help me with the same. I used if condition like
`if{$_REQUEST($_SESSION['role0'])
echo 'some lists';
}`
 if i used like this if condition nothing will display.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) prepared statements as described in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: _if{$_REQUEST($_SESSION['role0'])_ should be *if(isset($_REQUEST($_SESSION['role0'])) {*

Answer (score 0):

The session data is note stored in the $_REQUEST.

```
$_SESSION['role0']=$data1['roleId'];
$_SESSION['role1']=$data1['roleId'];
```

Both 'role0' and 'role1' will have the same value. It can be simplified to:

```
$_SESSION['role']=$data1['roleId'];
```

Then use:

```
if( $_SESSION['role'] === 1) {
    echo 'admin role 1';
    echo 'Show first half of menu';
} elseif ($_SESSION['role'] === 2) {
    echo 'Show second half of menu';
} else {
    echo 'Other or missing admin value. show no menu';
}
```

SQL injection is possible the way it is currently written. Prepared statements would be a good thing to add next.